# eclipselink: Missing Transaction with different jar's

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, transactions, eclipselink, jboss7.x

I have a JEE application. The classes of these JEE application are packaged in two different jar's which are both member of the EAR file.

Let's say I have a JPA Entity "DataEntity" (packaged in the jar "a.jar").

In the first JAR file "a.jar" is also stored following class:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class A_Bean {
  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "testApp")
  private EntityManager em;

  public void testMethod(DataEntity obj) {
    if (em.contains(obj) log.info("CONTAINED a 1");
    else {
      obj = em.merge(obj);
      em.refresh(obj);
    }
    if (em.contains(obj) log.info("CONTAINED a 2");
  }
}
```

In the second JAR file "b.jar" I have following class:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class B_Bean {
  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "testApp")
  private EntityManager em;

  public void testMethod(DataEntity obj) {
    if (em.contains(obj) log.info("CONTAINED b 1");
    else {
      obj = em.merge(obj);
      em.refresh(obj);
    }
    if (em.contains(obj) log.info("CONTAINED b 2");
  }
}
```

Now I assume the following calls will be called from outside of the EJB container (means the specified DataEntity "dataObj" is currently not managed by the EntityManager):

```
a.testMethod(dataObj);
```

shows the expected output:

```
CONTAINED a 2
```

But if I call

```
b.testMethod(dataObj);
```

I get a

```
Exception: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException
  at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.transactionIsRequired(AbstractEntityManager.java:692)
  at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.merge(AbstractEntityManager.java:547)
  at B_Bean.testMethod(B_Bean.java:xxx)
  ...
```

Also adding

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
```

not helps.

And now after I moving the class B_Bean into the a.jar file also the B_Bean class works as expected.

Must be packaged all EntityBeans in the same jar file? Is there is a trick how to package Entity classes in different jar files?

My Environment:

- JBoss 7.1.1
- eclipselink 2.5.1

Thanks,
Steffen

Comment: where do you packaged the persistence.xml file?

Comment: @Gabriel: In "a.jar". Is this the point why it works if the A.class is in a.jar?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there is a trick how to package Entity classes in different jar files?

[JPA specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1387374245_74b3b3203a7884d7c62a8ef97097a5c0) defines several persistence scopes.

> 8.2.2 Persistence Unit Scope
>   An EJB-JAR, WAR, application client jar, or EAR can define a persistence unit.

In your case the persistence.xml file packaged within the a.jar file defines a persistence unit that includes only the components defined this jar.

> A persistence unit that is defined at the level of an EJB-JAR, WAR, or application client jar is
>   scoped to that EJB-JAR, WAR, or application jar respectively and is visible to the components
>   defined in that jar or war.

You have several possibilities to expand the scope of your unit persistence. For example define a persistence unit at EAR level:

> A persistence unit that is defined at the level of the EAR is generally visible to all components
>   in the application...

Other possibility is to modify the persistence.xml included in a.jar and explicitly include a reference to b.jar.

> One or more JAR files may be specified using the jar-file elements instead of, or in addition to the
>   mapping files specified in the mapping-file elements. If specified, these JAR files will be searched
>   for managed persistence classes...Such JAR files are specified relative to the directory or jar file that contains the root of the persis-
>   tence unit.

```
<jar-file>b.jar</jar-file>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this not helps. At this time we change our architecture so that we have all EJB's and all Entity Beans in one jar.